# search through an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I don't know if this is the best solution but this is all I found after a long search:

I would like to search inside an array for mystring and if it's found to show me the country. That's what I've done so far but using arrays of structures is kinda complicated so I kindly request your help

```
char *mystring = "butter";

typedef struct user_data {
 char* company;
 char* country;
}user_data;


user_data comp[]={
    { .company = "Company selling Eggs", .country  = "United Kingdom" },
    { .company = "Company selling Butter", .country  = "United States" },
    .....................   //other structures (around 200)
};
```

*How can I use strcmp with that ?*

Comment: A loop? Use `sizeof(comp) / sizeof(comp[0])` to get the number of entries in the array.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp

Comment: @ShaMora is the loop the problem or strcmp(item.company, mystring)?

Comment: I think he want to find the occurrence of butter within the company string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `strstr()` and not `strcmp()`

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(comp)/sizeof(comp[0]); i++) {
    if (strstr(comp[i].company, mystring))
         printf("Country is: %s\n", comp[i].country)
}
```